# Using the same entity with different ORM entity managers

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need to connect with Doctrine and Symfony 3.4 to two different MySQL databases. They are configured as master-slave (one is master and the second is slave). I need to run some queries using Doctrine repositories only on slave connection and the rest of them on master. I've tried many types of configuration, but as the Symfony documentation says here, https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html, I am able to run queries on an entity only on a specific connection. That doesn't help me much.

Comment: What kind of queries / scenarios you have that you couldn't achieve with the options from the provided entity manager documentation? I.e. for example fetching a specific entity manager instance based on your action/function does sound like it could be used in your case.

Comment: Doctrine is working as designed.  Each entity manager is independent.  You should be able to run the same queries on different connections but the resulting entities themselves will not be related.

Comment: I have two different entity managers and I am trying to call same query (method from repository) with different connection.

Comment: And what happens?  Is the entity mapped to both managers?

Comment: No. Actually, this is what I need (the entity to be mapped on both manager). Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible.  Just follow the config example in the docs.  Just remember that you will get different instances of the same entity.  Which can potentially cause all sorts of interesting thing to occur.